# ADF doesnt create BlobCreation event with dataflow

Tags: eventtrigger, azure-data-factory

I have pipeline and a dataflow activity inside which copies the data to blob storage. I have trigger activated.

Problem is, the trigger works If I place the file manually on storage. But it doesn't get triggered when the dataflow puts file on the blob storage with copy activity.

Here is the trigger info:
[image]

Comment: My first thought is that the parquet is not being named the way you expect. Parquet is typically created as a group of files inside a folder, not specifically a single file. Can you verify the output of the DataFlow?

Comment: Hi,

I understand what you mean, but yes we have only one parquet file. Although, during the dataflow running I see a temporary folder having multiple parquet files but when the process is complete only a single parquet file is created and the temporary folder disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using web activity to send custom blob events to custom events and using custom triggers on the receiving pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a sink in dataflow when using parquet format generates a BlobRenamed event instead of BlobCreation. Therefore, the trigger doesn't get the right event.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it's working fine for me. it is detecting blob is getting added in particular container.

It appears that the trigger is set up to only react when new files are added to the blob storage and not when old files change. It's possible that the dataflow activity updates an existing file rather than producing a new one when it moves data to the blob storage.

Agreed with @Joel Cochran in **Blob path ends with** you are passing `train_data.parquet` if trigger did not find any particular file with name contain similar pattern it will not trigger the pipeline.

You may tweak the trigger to look for changes in both new and current files to fix this. This may be achieved by including the only `.parquet` in the **Blob path ends with** section of the trigger setup, which will make the trigger react to any changes to files in the supplied path.

[image]

Specify the correct details.

It's possible that the trigger is not configured to detect changes made by the dataflow activity. Check the trigger's settings to ensure that it is monitoring the correct blob container and that it is set up to detect the appropriate types of changes, such as new or modified blobs.

Comment: Hi,

I have the same setup. Its just the BlobPathEndsWith has value of train_data.parquet because there are 3 fles being generated by adf data flow and I want to trigger only with train_data file.

Comment: can you share all sample file names?

Comment: target_data.parquet, feature_data.parquet, train_data.parquet

Comment: you can simply pass this file with blob path in BlobPathStartsWith and keep BlobPathEndsWith empty.

Comment: Nah, I cannot because the adf create this file in multiple folders you can assume it generates train_data.parquet for multiple algorithms and then for each of these train_data.parquet another pipeline should trigger and use the respective parquet file.

If I fix this in BlobStartsWith then I cant have all the paths because adf doesn't support wildcard here

Comment: pass only file name in BlobPathEndsWith and BlobPathStartsWith keep empty it will detect all similar files in all folders. [image](https://i.imgur.com/a669uHc.png)

Comment: Hi, what you are suggesting Pratik it will not work. As @Obii mentioned I have the same problem and this happens only when the files is coming from a dataflow copy. If I upload the file from my computer it triggers perfectly